# Merge multiple list scraped from HTML using Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, web-scraping, append

I am trying to **scrape** the list of name from a web and need to list it in the form of Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

images = soup.find_all('img')
for elements in images:
  x = elements['alt'] # str
  y = elements['src'] # st
  if x != '':
  b = {'alt':[x], 'src':[y]}
  df = pd.DataFrame(b)
  print(df)
```

But, the Pandas output its not worked well as the title of the table is put on every name and source which supposed to be located on the top of the table.

```
alt                                    src
0  Crime Defender  admin/course_image/crime_defender.jpg
            alt                                   src
0  Abdul Vaheed  admin/trainer_image/abdul-vaheed.jpg
                  alt                                  src
0  Crime Investigator  admin/course_image/investigator.jpg
            alt                                   src
0  Abdul Vaheed  admin/trainer_image/abdul-vaheed.jpg
               alt                            src
0  Ethical Hacking  admin/course_image/hacker.jpg
               alt                               src
0  Dipendra Sharma  admin/trainer_image/dipendra.jpg
                      alt                          src
0  Pentester Professional  admin/course_image/pen1.jpg
               alt                               src
0  Dipendra Sharma  admin/trainer_image/dipendra.jpg
                     alt                             src
0  Pen Tester For Mobile  admin/course_image/android.png
            alt                                   src
0  Abdul Vaheed  admin/trainer_image/abdul-vaheed.jpg
                 alt                            src
0  Secure Programmer  admin/course_image/secure.png
            alt                                   src
0  Abdul Vaheed  admin/trainer_image/abdul-vaheed.jpg
                           alt                                   src
0  Fortify Web Security Expert  admin/course_image/websiteSecure.jpg
            alt                                   src
0  Abdul Vaheed  admin/trainer_image/abdul-vaheed.jpg
                            alt                           src
0  iOS APPLICATION EXPLOITATION  admin/course_image/apple.png
            alt                                   src
0  Abdul Vaheed  admin/trainer_image/abdul-vaheed.jpg
```

As it seems that every name is on their own list. I have tried using `append` to merge all the string inside the list, but it still not shown what the DataFrame Pandas should show. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add all dict in a list first then create dataframe and remove square brackets inside dict.

```
response_list = []
images = soup.find_all('img')
for elements in images:
  x = elements['alt'] # str
  y = elements['src'] # st
  if x != '':
    response_list.append({'alt':x, 'src':y})

df = pd.DataFrame(response_list)
print(df)
```